# Can a creature be killed by damage from two different instants?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

During a game, an opponent cast two instants, one after another. One did two damage to a creature, while the second instant did two damage and if that killed my creature, did 3 damage to me. My creature was a 4/4, so obviously it did 3 damage to me according to my opponent. Is that a legal move? Assuming the first instant resolved, would that leave my creature at a 4/2? Or would the card have no effect?

Comment: The first spell you mention could be any number of cards, but can you confirm that the second spell was [Searing Blood](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=378483)?

Answer (score 17):

Yes, that was a legal move.

You may cast multiple instants in the same turn. There's no limit beyond having the instants and being able to pay their cost.

After taking the first two damage, your 4/4 would still be a 4/4. Those two numbers represent power/toughness - toughness is not health, but the amount of damage a creature can withstand in one turn.

Your 4/4 would be a 4/4 with two damage marked against it after the first spell, then a 4/4 with four damaged marked against it after the second. Since it has taken damage at least equal to its toughness in one turn, it dies.

Comment: This brings up the question: Are there any ways to remove these damage counters?

Comment: @FreeAsInBeer You could ask that in its own question. "Is there any way to remove damage that's already been dealt?" or something.

Comment: @FreeAsInBeer incidentally, they're not counters. I guess you could use some sort of physical object to help you track how much damage a creature has taken in the turn so far, but counters are a separate thing in Magic, with a specific meaning in the rules.

Comment: @doppelgreener I'd thought about it, but found it was pertinent enough to the current discussion, while also probably being a rarely asked question so I figured I'd ask it as a comment instead of cluttering the question feed with something some would consider dumb.

Comment: @FreeAsInBeer Ask it as a new question. I don't think it's relevant (except that we're talking about damage), and leading on with questions isn't what comments are for. However, it's a good question - the answer might be "no except for this one card but here's some alternatives that are about as good" or something and I'd be interested to know. Let's put it this way: I think it's good enough that if you don't ask it, I probably will!

Comment: @doppelgreener [Here you go](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/24481/can-damage-counters-be-removed-from-creatures-before-they-die).